# PHP Curl HMAC-SHA1

Tags: php, api, curl, hmacsha1

Need help on this ....
I need to get json data from API call from a URL.
It said the called need..

1. Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded
2. HTTP HEADERS : key ---> APIKEY
3. HTTP HEADERS : sig ---> HMAC-SHA1 signature of POST Data with SECRET KEY
4. POST PARAMETER: timestamp  ----> Current Unix Timestamp

Do I do this correctly? But how to implement point 3 above???

```
$key = 'APIKEY';
$secret = 'APISECRET';
$signature = '';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.domain.com/getticker");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "timestamp=".time());
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded","key: ".$key,"sig: ".$signature));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $response;
```

Been scratching my head over this. please help me this newbie on PHP.

Comment: _“Been scratching my head over this”_ – looks like this (scratching) is the _only_ thing you have done …

Comment: Not really.... I have added

 $timestamp = time();
 $signature = hash_hmac('sha1', $timestamp, $secret);

it wont work still....

Comment: Your POST data is not simply the timestamp value, it is `timestamp=…`. And if there’s more parameters, then the argument separator (usually `&`) would most likely have to be included as well, and the _order_ will matter too.

Answer (score 5):

Finally I got it....
see the $signature part.

```
$key = 'APIKEY';
$secret = 'APISECRET';

$timestamp = time();
$signature = hash_hmac('sha1', "timestamp=".$timestamp, $secret);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.domain.com/getticker");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "timestamp=".time());
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded","key: ".$key,"sig: ".$signature));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $response;
```